# How to hide folders for people that have no access on Windows Home Server?

Tags: windows-home-server

I have **Windows Home Server 2011** running. I can create users and set their permissions on folders, however it would be nice to hide the folders they don't have access to anyways.

Is there a way you can do this, or manually tell a folder to be hidden for that user?